# Connect to Twitch IRC chat

Tags: php, sockets, irc, twitch

Hello i've tried to connect to the Twitch IRC Chat so i can try to make a simple chat bot for twitch but im struggling to make it work.

Error im getting: http://puu.sh/j3HwK/173a0388fb.png

and here is the code:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');


function IRCBot()
{
    function IRC()
    {
        $config = array(
                'server'  => 'irc.twitch.tv', 
                'port'    => 6667, 
                'channel' => '#spiritboar',
                'name'    => 'bin4rybot', 
                'nick'    => 'Bin4ryBOT', 
                'pass'    => 'oauth:##########################' //http://twitchapps.com/tmi/
        );

        echo 'test';
        $server = array();
        $server['connect'] = fsockopen($config['server'], $config['port']);

        if($server['connect'])
        {
            echo 'test2';
            SendData("PASS " . $config['pass'] . "\n\r");
            SendData("NICK " . $config['nick'] . "\n\r");
            SendData("USER " . $config['nick'] . "\n\r");
            SendData("JOIN " . $config['channel'] . "\n\r");

            while(!feof($server['connect']))
            {
                echo 'test3';
            }
        }
    }

    function SendData($cmd)
    {
        global $server;
        fwrite($server['connect'], $cmd, strlen($cmd));
        echo "[SEND] $cmd <br>";
    }

    IRC();

}

IRCBot();

?>
```

So basicly i cant make it connect to the Twitch IRC, Please if someone can help me it would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

I know it was asked soo manny years ago, but perhaps can help someone else today:

```
<?php    
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
$server = array();    

function IRCBot()
{
    function IRC()
    {
        $server global;
        $config = array(
                'server'  => 'ssl://irc.chat.twitch.tv', 
                'port'    => 6697, 
                'channel' => '#twitch_channel',
                'nick'    => strtolower('twitch_username'), 
                'pass'    => 'oauth:twitch_oauth_token' //http://twitchapps.com/tmi/
        );

        $server['connect'] = @fsockopen($config['server'], $config['port']);

        if($server['connect'])
        {
            echo "[<] Starting connection with user: " . $config['nick'];
            SendData('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags');
            SendData('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/commands');
            SendData('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/membership');
            SendData("PASS " . $config['pass']);
            SendData("NICK " . $config['nick']);
            SendData("USER " . $config['nick'] . "  1 1 :" . $config['nick']);
            SendData("JOIN " . $config['channel']);

            while(!feof($server['connect']))
            {
               $server['READ_BUFFER'] = fgets($server['connect'], 1024);
               echo "[>] " . $server['READ_BUFFER'];
               flush();
            }
        }
    }

    function SendData($cmd)
    {
        global $server;
        @fwrite($server['connect'], $cmd . "\r\n");
        echo "[<] $cmd \r\n";
    }

    IRC();

}

IRCBot();
```

The most important thing to notice beyond the format of the commands send to twitch, it's that the SendData function **does not send strlen** on the fwrite function and the  **"\r\n"** append to command string.

Comment: Thanks for the script. I have put my credentials .. Everything is working except for chat messages list. `$data = fgets($server['connect'],256); echoo "[>] " . $data` 

This does not work for me. Can you tell me why ?

Comment: you have a error in `echoo [>]`... its **echo**... and the length of the message  its different (**256** instead of  **1024**) _idk if that affect the answer from twitch but maybe your error could be there_

Comment: I had to change line 10 to `global $server;` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In your `IRC()` function, you've declared `$server`, but not marked it as a global variable, thus it's not available in `SendData(...)`.

`SendData(...)` then looks at the global version of `$server`, finds that it's not got an array element called `connect`, so returns null, which is where your error is coming from.

Add a `global $server;` before `$server = array();`, and try again.

As a second point, I think the line returns need to be `\r\n` instead of `\n\r`, but I'm not sure - it will depend on how strict the IRC server is.

Comment: Thanks for the updates in script. I have put my credentials .. Everything is working except for chat messages list. `$data = fgets($server['connect'],256); echoo "[>] " . $data` 

This does not work for me. Can you tell me why ?